# How to change order of axis ticks for a ternary diagram?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, axis, ternary

Is it possible to reverse scale, for example for AC from 0.1-1 to 1-0.1?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to a statement on [`github 12.09.2019`](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4010) this was not possible back then:

> We don't offer a way to do this at the moment unfortunately. This
> would make a great addition to the library though.

And taking a closer look at the structure of a [ternary](https://plotly.com/python/ternary-plots/#ternary-scatter-plot-with-plotly-graph-objects) axis, there does not seem to be an attribute that lets you change the order of the axes:

```
layout.ternary.Aaxis({
    'color': '#444',
    'exponentformat': 'B',
    'gridcolor': 'white',
    'gridwidth': 1,
    'hoverformat': '',
    'layer': 'above traces',
    'linecolor': 'white',
    'linewidth': 1,
    'min': 0,
    'minexponent': 3,
    'nticks': 6,
    'separatethousands': False,
    'showexponent': 'all',
    'showgrid': True,
    'showline': True,
    'showticklabels': True,
    'tickfont': {'color': '#2a3f5f', 'family': '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif', 'size': 12},
    'tickformat': 'g',
    'tickmode': 'auto',
    'tickprefix': '',
    'ticks': '',
    'ticksuffix': '',
    'title': {'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f', 'family': '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif', 'size': 14},
              'text': 'Joly'}
})
```

Comment: Yeah, this feature probably won't be available until someone submits a PR. Would a possible workaround be to plot the values generated from (1.0-A) instead of the values for A and supply the ticks arrays in reverse order?

Comment: @DerekO Haven't tried it. But it certainly seems like a possibility!

Answer (score 1):

A [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot) plot MUST have the axes such that for any given axis at value of 1 the other two axes have a value of 0 (assuming sum of 1)... thus reversing an axis would reverse the other two axes.

So for the question of...

> Is it possible to reverse scale, for example for AC from 0.1-1 to
> 1-0.1?"

...the answer is no, not possible to reverse just one axis.

@vestland points out [this question](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4010) but this case is for using only two dimensions in ternary plot, and judging by the picture provided in the question asked above this is not the case.